# Compare all the lists contained in a nested list to get only the strings that match

Tags: python, sorting, compare, nested-lists, matching

I want to compare all the lists contained in a nested list to have at the end the pair word who corresponding.

I manage this with 2 different lists to get the strings that match in each list.

In this way :

```
listA = [['Test1','Test2','Test3'], ['Test1','Test4','Test2']]
listB = [['Test1','Test2','Test5'], ['Test10','Test4','Test2']]
```

The result I obtain :

```
['Test1', 'Test2'] # Matched at [('Test1,'Test2'),'Test3'] -> [('Test1','Test2'),'Test5']

['Test2'] # Matched at ['Test1','Test4',('Test2')] -> ['Test1',('Test2'),'Test5']

['Test4', 'Test2'] # Matched at ['Test1',('Test4','Test2)] -> ['Test10',('Test4','Test2')]
```

We notice in this example that 'Test3, Test5 and Test10' are not in the result because none match with the other lists.

I would like to do it with a single nested list.

```
list = [['Test1','Test2','Test3'], ['Test1','Test4','Test2'], ['Test1','Test2','Test5'], ['Test5','Test4','Test2']]
```

Here the code I use with two list :

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile
    
for x in listB:
    for y in listA:

        counterA = Counter(x)
        counterB = Counter(y)
        
        count = counterA + counterB

        count = dict(count)

        prompt_match = [k for k in count if count[k] == 2]

        print(prompt_match)
```

The code is not perfect with the 2 lists because I get duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `set` intersection in list comprehension

```
from itertools import product
listA = [['Test1','Test2','Test3'], ['Test1','Test4','Test2']]
listB = [['Test1','Test2','Test5'], ['Test10','Test4','Test2']]
set(tuple(set(x)&set(y)) for x,y  in product(listA, listB))

# output
{('Test1', 'Test2'), ('Test2',), ('Test4', 'Test2')}

For nested list use below approach
from itertools import combinations
listA = [['Test1','Test2','Test3'], ['Test1','Test4','Test2'], ['Test1','Test2','Test5'], ['Test10','Test4','Test2']]
set(tuple(set(x)&set(y)) for x,y  in combinations(listA, 2))
# output
{('Test1', 'Test2'), ('Test2',), ('Test4', 'Test2')}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like to do it with wingle nested list, I specified it in my subject. 

I find your answer perfect when it's for 2 different lists !

Comment: Its almost same thing also the list you have shown in the question is incorrect. Please check, [[],[]] [[],[]] -> this is overall tuple.

Comment: Indeed it is a mistake, I corrected it. I want to do it with a nested list as follows [[],[],[],[]]

Comment: @cyber_working done the change now see

Comment: Thank you I searched so long on my side, for such a quick resolution!

Comment: @cyber_working can you upvote it it you like it

Comment: I need "15 reputation" to cast a vote